# Streaming files from SFTP to SMB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stream, sftp, smb

I'm attempting to use NodeJS script to copy files from an SFTP server to an SMB share, but only if the files are newer than 3 days old. I have the bare bones of the code here, but I'm stumbling over the obvious bit; getting the file from SFTP as a stream, so I can write to SMB as a stream. The files might be quite large, so I want to avoid using local storage in a download/re-upload cycle.

```
const path = require('path');
const sftp = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const smb2 = require('smb2');
const config = require('./config');

function extractTimestamp(filename) {...} // works fine
function calculateAgeFromTimestamp(timestamp) {...} // also works fine

async function processFiles() {
  const sftpClient = new sftp();
  const smbClient = new smb2(config.smb);

  try {
    await sftp.connect(config.sftp);
    console.log(`Listing remote SFTP source: ${config.sourceDir}`);
    const files = await sftp.list(config.sourceDir);

    if (files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No files found on SFTP.');
      return;
    }

    for (const file of files) {
      const sourceFilePath = path.join(config.sourceDir, file.name);
      const destinationFilePath = config.smb.share + '\\' + file.name;

      const timestamp = extractTimestamp(file.name);
      const fileAgeDays = calculateAgeFromTimestamp(timestamp);

      if (fileAgeDays <= 3) {
        const exists = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          smbClient.exists(destinationFilePath, (err, exists) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error checking file existence on SMB:', err);
              reject(err);
            } else {
              resolve(exists);
            }
          });
        });

        if (!exists) {
          console.log('Found file to copy');

          // !!!confusing stream code goes here
         
        } else {
          console.log('File already exists');
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  } finally {
    sftp.end();
    smbClient.close();
  }
}

processFiles();
```

Can I use some sort of wrapper to turn the reading from SFTP into a stream?

Comment: Seems like [`get`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#org252a716) can write to a stream.

Comment: Err, sftp.get? I want to write FROM the sftp TO the smb. So reading a stream from the sftp source, writing to a stream on the smb destination. So I still need to be able to stream the FROM the smb client. Is that correct? Or have I misunderstood your point?

Comment: `Err, sftp.get? I want to write FROM the sftp TO the smb.` Yeah, so you want to __get__ something from SFTP, no?

Comment: Yes, but I also want to WRITE that thing that I get to smb. I tried using fs to turn smb into a writestream, but not joy.

Comment: I would suggest using this lib for smb2 -> https://github.com/tracker1/node-smb2, it supports createWriteStream, with `ssh2-sftp-client.createReadStream` + `smb2Client.createReadStream` things can be resolved. should be something similar to
`const oldFile = fs.createReadStream('./text.txt');`
`const newFile = fs.createWriteStream('./newFile.txt');`
`oldFile.on('data', fileData => newFile.write(fileData)) `

Comment: Thanks Hamza, but "This repository has been archived by the owner on Sep 10, 2019. It is now read-only.", and it doesn't handle the Node17 openssl issue :-(